# Como mesclar uma lista de df mantendo a coluna data?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
import pandas as pd
t1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "data": ["01/01/2022", "02/01/2022", "03/01/2022", "04/01/2022"],
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
    }
)

t2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "data": ["01/01/2022", "02/01/2022", "03/01/2022", "04/01/2022"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    }
)

t3 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "data": ["01/01/2022", "02/01/2022", "03/01/2022", "04/01/2022"],
        "E": ["E0", "E1", "E2", "E3"],
        "F": ["F0", "F1", "F2", "F3"],
    }
)


result = pd.merge([t1, t2, t3], on="data")
result
```

TypeError: merge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right'

Answer (score 0):

O método `merge` somente junta DOIS dataframes. Veja a documentação [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)

Você pode fazer este merge com a linha abaixo:

```
result = pd.merge(t1, t2, on="data").merge(t3, on="data")
result
```

O resultado será

```
         data   A   B   C   D   E   F
0  01/01/2022  A0  B0  C0  D0  E0  F0
1  02/01/2022  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1
2  03/01/2022  A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  F2
3  04/01/2022  A3  B3  C3  D3  E3  F3
```

Outra opção é concatenar horizontalmente os dataframes baseado no índice usando o método [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

```
pd.concat([t1.set_index("data"), t2.set_index("data"), t3.set_index("data")], axis=1)
```

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, poderia dizer o motivo para que eu possa melhorar a resposta?